# Flutter MaterialPageRoute doesn't navigate over native iOS navigatorViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, flutter

I have opened a native storyboard UIViewController using FlutterMethodChannel call from Flutter section. Now I a want navigate to other widget/view using method call from iOS(swift) section.
There is no problem in method calling and routing portion except one. The new view that I have navigated from flutter section by invokeMethod from iOS code, is covered by current iOS view. That is new flutter navigation widget is under iOS UIViewController that I have opened from flutter method "await platform.invokeMethod('Printy');". I want to navigate over current iOS UIViewController.

AppDelegate.swift

```
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    var navigationController: UINavigationController?
    var CHANNEL: FlutterMethodChannel?
    
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        let controller = window.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        CHANNEL = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.flutter.epic/epic", binaryMessenger: controller as! FlutterBinaryMessenger)
        CHANNEL?.setMethodCallHandler { [unowned self] (methodCall, result) in
            if methodCall.method == "Printy" {
                self.newViewController(result)
            }
        }

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        
        navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    func newViewController(_ result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard? = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
        let window: UIWindow = ((UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!)!
        let paytmTransactionController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PaytmTransactionController") as! PaytmTransactionController
        paytmTransactionController.result = result
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(paytmTransactionController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

PaytmTransactionController.swift

```
class PaytmTransactionController: UIViewController {
    var result: FlutterResult?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    
    @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func showFlutterView(_ sender: Any) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)!.CHANNEL!.invokeMethod("didRecieveTranscript", arguments: nil)
    }
}
```

Flutter -> App.dart

```
class AppState extends State<App> {
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
    new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  final channelName = 'com.flutter.epic/epic';
  final methodChannel = MethodChannel(channelName);
  methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this._didRecieveTranscript);
}

Future<void> _didRecieveTranscript(MethodCall call) async {
  final String utterance = call.arguments;
  switch (call.method) {
    case "didRecieveTranscript":
      openMyProject(utterance);
      break;
    case "didRecieveNativeViewFactory":
      didRecieveNativeViewFactory(utterance);
      break;
  }
}

Future<void> didRecieveNativeViewFactory(utterance) async {
  navigatorKey.currentState
      .pushNamed("/project", arguments: ScreenArguments());
}

Future<void> openMyProject(utterance) async {
  navigatorKey.currentState
      .pushNamed("/project", arguments: ScreenArguments());
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // TODO: implement build
  if (this._locale == null) {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  } else {
    return Provider(
      create: (context) => ApiService.create(),
      child: ZoningProvider(
        child: GlobalProvider(
          child: DashboardProvider(
            child: AuthProvider(
              child: MaterialApp(
                title: GlobalVariable.appTitle,
                theme: ThemeData(
                    //fontFamily: FontClass.defaultRegular,
                    ),
                onGenerateRoute: RouterClass().router,
                navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
                supportedLocales: [
                  Locale('en', 'US'),
                  Locale('zh', 'Chinese'),
                ],
                localizationsDelegates: [
                  AppLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                ],
                localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
                  for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
                    if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
                        supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
                      return supportedLocale;
                    }
                  }
                  return supportedLocales.first;
                },
                locale: _locale,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After exploring two days, I have found a solution. It's simple, just call "SystemNavigator.pop()" to pop the iOS route from the Flutter side.